# How can I print items barcode sticker in DataGridView Upon the number of items

Tags: vb.net

Greeting !
How can I print `items` `barcode sticker` in DataGridView
I used this code but it reprints all items

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DGVItem.Rows.Count - 1
PrintBarCode.PrintToPrinter(DGVItem.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value, False, 0, 0)
Next
```

I just want to print ten barcode stickers not 60 barcode stickers

-------Code---Item---Price---Quantity---Total

Row1----1-----Item1---100--------2--------200

Row2----2-----Item2---150--------4--------600

Row3----3-----Item3---200--------5--------1000

Row4----4-----Item4---250--------4--------1000

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks51e.jpg)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you perhaps re-phrase your question some?  What exactly does "based on quantity" mean?  What is PrintBarCode in this context?

Comment: Hello sir
In my project I want to print barcode Sticker  for each item that the total number of barcode  stickers is equal to the number of items

Comment: You'd need to get the value from the Quantity column and then loop printing on that value.